# Big Commerce: Display all products on specific custom _page.html

Tags: bigcommerce

I have never used Bigcommerce before and an trying to customize a previous website for a client. I have looked through as much documentation as I can handle and can't figure out which panel, or GLOBAL, or what I need to simply display all product on a specific page.

On my default page I have used `%%Panel.SideNewProducts` which displays the newest specified number of products, which works fine. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to display every product in my store.

Comment: what would you do if you had a thousands products ?, An answer could be third party using the api

Comment: I actually looked into that, and honestly I don't know. I have been given little direction and like I said it was already a bigcommerce site, but he wanted a bunch of things customized because it looked pretty bad. With the API do you just do the site in PHP and pull everything from his bigcommerce account?